# Dart calculation or rounding error for math results where result length is 19?

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, math

I have a simple code to test math in dart:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Test(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final TextEditingController t1 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController t2 = TextEditingController();
  
//   static var f = NumberFormat('#,##,###.##', 'en_IN');
  static String displayResult = '';
  
  void math(){
    setState(() {
      double n1 = double.parse(t1.text);
      double n2 = double.parse(t2.text);

      double result = n1 * n2 / 100;
      print(result);
      displayResult = result.toStringAsFixed(2);  
    });
    
    
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: t1,
          
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: t2,
        ),
        Text(
          displayResult
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('DO Math'),
          onPressed: math,),
        
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I type the following value:

```
t1 = 586665578588 & t2 = 999999999
```

The result output is:
[image]

The print to console before converting the above result toStringAsFixed(2) give the result as:

[image]

The console output matches to the calculation in excel as well. But the conversion to string somehow alters the number.

I tried an online calculator and the results are bit different:

[image]

Can you please help me why we see different values as output.

Comment: You compared the results of using arithmetic with `double`s to a calculator that explicitly advertises itself as a *full precision* calculator.  An IEEE-754 double-precision floating pointer number does have infinite precision; it has only 53 bits for its significand. `t1 * t2` is *much* greater than 2^53.  If you want to do arbitrary precision arithmetic in Dart, consider using something like [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal).

Comment: Will check the package. But what about the difference when the result is converted to text. Any idea why that's happening?